# Why does not isinstance() accept a set of types?

Tags: python

It really bugs me why wouldn't `isinstance(value, type_or_types)` accept a `set()` of types if it accepts `tuple`.

Basically why:

```
isinstance(1.23, (int, float, complex))
```

is valid, but:

`isinstance(1.23, {int, float, complex})`

is not?.

I've noticed that for the latter case, up to Python 3.9 it throws the error:

```
TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types
```

while from 3.10 the error has changed to:

```
TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type, a tuple of types, or a union
```

After I saw `union` I felt something might have changed in the newer versions, but I don't get what. What is a union? I only know the method `set.union()` which in turn returns another `set`, so I'm basically stuck without being able to use it.

EDIT:
I suspect the reason is the mutability?

Comment: It probably refers to a union of types as defined in the [typing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union) module.

Comment: @ThePhoton Yes, that's correct. An example with a union would be `isinstance(1.23, int | float | complex)` which uses a union of the three types.

Comment: https://peps.python.org/pep-0604/ Discusses adding support for unions to `isinstance()`, but I didn't find anything talking about sets. At the risk of falling into pure opinion, I'd guess sets of types are not supported because we don't need them? Do you have a use case where it would be advantageous to be able to use a set?

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I see now what Union is. Regarding the use case, it would be useful for my application but maybe for no one else. In my case I do some type validations where some of types are redundant (e.g. numbers.Integer is equivalent to int, np.int16, np.int32, etc. Same for float, and complex) so I am using sets to remove that redundancy. Of course I can just type ``isinstance(..., tuple(myset))`` but I really wondered why a set wouldn't be accepted as an argument in the first place (even if isinstance() tuple-ized the argument under the hood)

Comment: And at least the ``set`` has the advantage that no type is repeated, so you ensure only one validation per type.